# I can't run gdb in emacs

Tags: debugging, gdb, prompt

I want to debug some C++ code in emacs with `gdb`. I tried to enter `gdb` with the command:

```
M-x RET gdb RET
```

Then I get a prompt that reads:

```
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n])
```

Whatever I type, the exact same prompt comes up. I can run gdb from the command line perfectly fine and compiled it with `g++ main.cpp -o main -g`. However, inside of emacs, I can't.

I encountered something similar while trying to type input in the compilation buffer which I couldn't do. There the command `C-u M-x compile` command helped. I wanted to try this in this scenario as well but still the same prompt comes up over and over again. I don't have much experience with emacs in general so I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs isn’t expecting a prompt from GDB here, so just change your GDB configuration so that there is no prompt. A quick search that anyone could have done suggests that adding `set debuginfod enabled` to your ~/.gdbinit file will fix it.

Comment: I didn't have that file. I created it, added the snippet. But it still shows up. I also added that `off` option afterwards.. Didn't work

Comment: I also have a ~/.gdbinit file and adding it above the python script and it worked with the `off` option. Thanks

Comment: I think the correct config file now is `~/.gdbinit`, not `~/.gdbrc`

Comment: It’s always been `~/.gdbinit`, as far as I know. It’s just that every other program in the world uses a filename that ends in `rc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a recent regression.  That's not the way it used to behave.

Sometimes, when `M-x gdb RET` fails, `M-x gud-gdb RET` still works.  The `gud-gdb` mode doesn't have a rich graphical interface, so it's not the best debugging that emacs offers.  However, it still shows the current line in your source code when single-stepping, so it's still better than gdb alone.  If your only goal is to use gdb from emacs, this may work for you.

You will need to know gdb commands to use `gud-gdb`.